# I cannot install nodemon by using npm command

Tags: node.js, express, npm, installation, nodemon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSr9J.jpg)

When i tried to install nodemon package using **npm** i got errors as shown in the picture. I also tried using **sudo** but nothing changed.

Comment: You didn't place `sudo` first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command.

`sudo npm install nodemon -g`

`sudo` makes sure that the command would run as a superuser that allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user (normally the superuser, or root).

`-g` instructs npm to install the node package globally onto the system.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: I tried with sudo but not working

Comment: @Assim you are using ```npm sudo  install nodemon -g ```. use ```sudo npm install nodemon -g```  instead.